# column command not handling escape sequences as expected?

Tags: bash

I have a working script checking mimetypes i.e. `text/x-diff`; `image/svg+xml` etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

mimetype="$1"

_Bold="\e[1m"
_unBold="\e[22m"

output="${_Bold}Testing MimeType${_unBold}:\t${mimetype}\n\t---------------"

get_default() {
xdg-mime query default "$1"
}

alias_of=`grep "^$mimetype " /usr/share/mime/aliases | cut -d' ' -f2`
if [ -n "$alias_of" ]; then
    default=`get_default $alias_of`
    output="$output\nWhich is an alias of:\t$alias_of\t-> ${default:-"none"}"
else
    output="$output\nWhich is not an alias."
    alias_of=$mimetype
fi

while : ; do
    subclass_of=`grep "^$alias_of " /usr/share/mime/subclasses | cut -d' ' -f2`
    if [ -n "$subclass_of" ]; then
      default=`get_default $subclass_of`
      output="$output\nWhich is a subclass of:\t$subclass_of\t-> ${default:-"none"}"

      alias_of=$subclass_of
    else
      output="$output\nWhich is not a subclass"
      break
    fi
done

echo -e $output | column -t -s$'\t'
```

Output **without bold** is as expected:

```
Testing MimeType:        text/rss
                         -------------
Which is an alias of:    application/rss+xml  -> none
Which is a subclass of:  application/xml      -> none
Which is a subclass of:  text/plain           -> vim.desktop
```

but **with bold** it changes:

```
Testing MimeType:                          text/rss
                         -------------
Which is an alias of:    application/rss+xml  -> none
Which is a subclass of:  application/xml      -> none
Which is a subclass of:  text/plain           -> vim.desktop
```

I have removed the rest of the formatting in my example, but with colors added it gets much worse.

I have narrowed it down to the `column` somehow including the escape sequences in its spacing. The same thing happens in xterm, gnome-terminal and urxvt.

Is this expected behaviour? I'm learning a lot but sometimes I get a headscratcher like this one.

Comment: If the issue is that `column` is treating the escape characters as printable characters in how it counts to format columns that makes sense (naive counting) but does seem unfortunate (and something that it could, potentially, handle better). The question is does it make sense for it to handle it better. It doesn't know that the output is going to a terminal that will not print them. They could end up being printed in the end.

Comment: Unquoted `$output` in the `echo` line is potentially doing things you don't want also (like losing internal runs of spaces and expanding globs if they happen to be there).

Comment: That makes so much sense, I didn't think of that. An option to pass them on would have been ideal.  I should look into other ways of formatting output, like printf maybe.  Thanks for catching that last line and thank you for your insight.

Comment: Right, `column` could get an option that told it to assume a terminal and handle non-printing characters appropriately. I'd see if newer versions can do that possibly.

Comment: I have just gotten in touch with a developer on the linux-utils mailing list and he says I "could be on to something" and an upcoming patch to `more` is related in some way. Will keep this post updated.